# Share abbreviations between major modes in abbrev-mode (Emacs)

Tags: emacs, abbreviation

I'd like to ask whether there is a way to share abbreviation definitions for `abbrev-mode` between several major modes. E.g.: in `LaTeX-mode` I'd like to have not only the `latex-mode` abbrevs (and of course the global ones) but also all those defined for `text-mode` and `org-mode`. Is copy/paste the only possibility? I hope not...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the list of abbreviation sources active in a given mode is stored in the list variable `ac-sources` (You can peek at the content of that variable at any time with `C-h v`). So, if you want the abbreviations of `modeA` to also be active in `modeB`, all you have to do is to define an appropriate hook:

```
 (add-hook 'B-mode-hook
                  (lambda ()
                    (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-modeA)
                    ))
```